# Setting PATH in Makefile run by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bash, path

I have a Makefile which runs fine from a bash shell, but fails to run from Eclipse. This is because the path I am setting in my .bash_profile is not getting used.

What is the best way of making this happen? Is there somewhere else I could put the path, to make sure it is invoked in non-interactive shells (which is I assume how eclipse is running make)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CDT, you can set environment variables in Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Environment. But I'm not sure this will achieve the desired effect.

You can also ( if using CDT, and an external builder ) you can set the make program to be `/bin/bash make` which should pick up your path.

Comment: you should set the make program to be "bash -c make". Otherwise bash will try to execute "make" as a bash script, and it will error out because it's a binary file. The "-c" option says to run commands from the string following "-c". Check the bash manpage for more info.